# Create a CSV file with two lists that include UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have 2 lists one of them include Persian words and the other one include numbers

```
Headers = ['word', 'value']
list1 = ['سلام', 'خوبی']
list2 = [1, 2]
```

i want to make the csv file like this

```
value          word
1              سلام
2             خوبی
```

this is my code, but it doesn't work on uft-8 chars

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': list1, 'class': list2})
    df.to_csv('milad.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and this is the result

```
word              value
Ù‡Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‡ Ø§Ùˆ     1
Ù‡Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‡ Ø§Ùˆ     2
```

how should I do that

Comment: Have you tried using the pandas library?

Comment: @ChengAnWong yes but it doesn't work on uft-8 chars

Comment: @ChengAnWong i added my code

Comment: Mine is working fine with your persian words, what's the error code?

Comment: Try not specifying the encoding

Comment: @ChengAnWong i added the result of my code

Comment: How are you viewing your result? It looks like the software that you are using to view it does not support UTF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be with the program you are using to open the resulting .csv file rather than with your python code. What program are you using?

When I executed your code and opened the resulting file in Notepad the characters displayed correctly,

```
words,class


1,سلام
2,خوبی
```

however when I open it in excel it produced the same issue you had.

```
word              value
Ù‡Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‡ Ø§Ùˆ     1
Ù‡Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‡ Ø§Ùˆ     2
```

You may need to tell the software you are using to open the csv file to use UTF-8. e.g. https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-utf8-excel-63726.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string into bytes before writing.

```
for x in enumerate(list1):
    list1[x[0]] = x[1].encode('utf-8')
```

This will change it to:

```
[b'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85', b'\xd8\xae\xd9\x88\xd8\xa8\xdb\x8c']
```

You can decode this later with `decode('utf-8')`

After writing,

```
d = open('test.csv','r').read()
```

Result:

```
,word,value

0,b'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85',b'\xd8\xae\xd9\x88\xd8\xa8\xdb\x8c'

1,1,2
```

Which you can then decode and read to pandas, hope this helped.